# Change spacing between navigation links in HTML / CSS

Tags: html, css

I wanted to reduce the space between my links for the navigation on the left side. I tried `padding` but it messes with my `float`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>projekt</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li class="home"><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
                <li class="nav"><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
                <li class="nav"><a href="list.html">list</a></li>
                <li class="nav"><a href="office.html">office</a></li>
                <li class="nav"><a href="projects.html">projects</a></li>
                <li class="nav"><a href="plans.html">plans</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

    </header>
    <div class="navline"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
nav ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: proxima-n-w01-reg,sans-serif;
    list-style-type: none;
}


.navline
{
    border-bottom:1px solid rgb(226, 223, 223);
    padding-bottom:80px
}

nav li.home{
    display: flex;
    margin: 30px 0 0 160px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;

}

nav li.nav{
    display: flex;
    margin: 30px 100px 0 0px;
    float: right;
    font-size: 18px;
}

nav li a{
    display: flex;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
   }
```

Should I not use `float` to position my navigations on the left and right side and rather `display:flex` and also to reduce the space?

Solution would be like:

```
plans  projects office ....
```

But it's more like this:

```
plans       projects     office...
```

Comment: **Margin right is 100px** which might be your major point of concern. But, for an effective usage, try the css code mentioned in my answer. That way of CSS will help you in future projects as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your CSS file, this is the example css file for a nav bar. You can add the missing attributes for the specific class in your css file. This would solve your purpose.

```
ul.nav {
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    background-color:#62564A;
    text-align:center;
    font-family: sans-serif; 
}
.nav li { 
    display:inline-block;
    width:33%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.nav a {
    text-align:center;
    padding:12px 0 13px 0;
    margin:0;
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    display:block;
}
.nav a:hover { 
    background:#A26A42;
    border:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to decrease the size of the margin ..

```
nav li.nav{
    display: flex;
    margin: 30px 20px 0 0px;
    float: right;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

Comment: But I want it to be 100px away from the right side. If I use 20px the space between the links is shorter but it's too close to the right side of the site.

Answer (score 0):

There's no point of adding `display:flex` on `li`. Logically, I would say this css code for `li` as incorrect. Instead modify your css this way:

```
nav ul{
    margin: 30px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: proxima-n-w01-reg,sans-serif;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly; /* You may also play around this css attribute for evenly distributed spacing instead of applying margin or so on li tag */
}
nav ul > li{
    margin: 0 10px; /* You may change this spacing as per your need */
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
nav ul > li > a{
    display: block;
}
```

I'll usually suggest applying `margin-top` on `ul` instead of individual `li` but that depends on you also.

Comment: But the space between the links doesn't get shorter.

Comment: Remove **`justify-content: space-evenly;`** line of code and check. *Note: Use this line of code only if you want to evenly distribute the total spacing available.*